# Python: Removing punctuation from read-in text using translate method

Tags: python

I'm trying to open and read a file, split the contents into words, and then iterate through them and remove all the punctuation. Why is this returning a `TypeError: expected a character buffer object` and how can I fix it?

```
with open(self.filename, "r") as file_opened:
    text = file_opened.read()
    words_with_punct = text.split()
    remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n' + string.punctuation))
    for i in words_with_punct:
        words = i.translate(remove)
    return words
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = file_opened.read().translate(None,string.punctuation)
```

should work fine not sure what all the other stuff your doing is supposed to do